# Is it correct to make a database query every single time a user requests an authenticated resource?

Tags: database, authentication, session, caching

Let's say you're using postgres for session management. Then, a user goes to access some content that requires a membership.

Do you really need to hit the database and check whether the session is in the database (and the user has the required membership level) on every single request to an authenticated resource? For example, they can be navigating around and try viewing 15 pieces of content in a couple minutes. Are you really hitting the database 15 times?

1. Am I right, but this is all negligible, and you're meant to hit the database this frequently?
2. Is it not an issue because postgresQL is smart enough to cache the query?
3. Is it insane to use postgresQL or MySQL for storing sessions, and one should always use something like Reddis?
4. Something else?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.